# How to dynamic include Javascript with multiple object instance

Tags: javascript, include

I have written a library in javascript and to optimize the loading I want to split the code with files that are loaded dynamically if necessary.

It works fine if I create a single instance of the library, but if I create several instances, nothing works. Here is a small example of the current structure I use.

A script on my page instantiates a "calculator" object, it is my basic library that is loaded with the page.

Then I call a method (addition). This method, which does not exist natively in my "calculator" library, is then loaded dynamically (dependency file). I use include.js to load my script dynamically. When I check the network tab of my navigator, the file is correctly loaded but the function is not executed (in the multi-instances scenario)

If I use only one instance, it's ok and the console shows 5. But if I use another instance there is no output, the method Tools.add() is not fired.

Thank you very much for your help, I tried tons of things without success. I really need to split the library into several parts and to use multiple instances of it. Maybe I don't have the correct approach?

Code on main html page

```
<script src="component.js"></script>
<script>
            var instance1 = new Calculator();
            instance1.Addition(2, 3);

            var instance2 = new Calculator();
            instance2.Addition(4, 6);
</script>
```

component.js

```
var Calculator = function () {
    this.Addition = function (a, b) {
        include(['dependency.js'], function () {
            console.log(Tools.add(a, b));
        });
    };

    this.Multiply = function (a, b) {
        console.log(a * b);
    };

};
```

dependency.js which is loaded dynamically

```
var Tools = (function () {
    return {
        add: function (a, b) {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: what is the output you get and what should be the expected output?

Comment: If I use only one instance it works, and the console shows "5" (2+3) but if I use a second instance like in the example, there is no output, the method Tools.add is not fired

Comment: this happens because the dependency is already loaded first time by 1st instance and is not reloaded, so it does not fire event. You should handle your dependencies centraly, eg use `requirejs` or similar. That would work

Comment: Thank you but if I use 2 instances, the first doesn't fire, not only the second one

Comment: then there is some problem with `includejs` maybe the path is not correct for your server. Open your network tab in browser tools and see if dependency.js is indeed loaded

Comment: it is possible there is some problem or misconfiguration with `includejs` library. Maybe it cannot handle multiple requests or sth like that. Try with `requirejs`

Comment: Thank you for your advice of using require.js, it solved the problem. There is a bug with include.js